# C# Removing List Item with same value but different identity, works, but why?

Tags: c#, list, identity, equality

I was trying to make a code that removes some list items, but then I realized, my code is not supposed to be working, but works.

I will explain the reason why I thought that my code 'should not be working' at the bottom of this document, but let me explain the scenario itself first.

**Basic concept of my code**

To perform some fitting logics per each node of a path when a path is given.

Details are:

1. Every nodes are likely to have an incoming direction from a previous node, and/or outgoing direction to a next node, unless the path is a single-noded.
2. Assumes that the incoming/outgoing directions are always aligned either horizontally or vertically.

   - In other words, the path can only move towards 4 way directions, x and y
3. I want to place a cap on unused sides.

   - for example, if the incoming direction is left and outgoing direction is right, I want to place a cap on the top and the bottom.

Testing code that is not supposed to be working, but works:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

struct Dir //mock-up object
{
    public int fooboo;  //dummy value to be printed, to distinguish each objects

    public Dir(int val) => fooboo = val;

    //these are "Dir a"
    public static readonly Dir forward = new Dir(1);
    public static readonly Dir back = new Dir(2);
    public static readonly Dir left = new Dir(3);
    public static readonly Dir right = new Dir(4);

    public override string ToString() => fooboo.ToString();
}

public class HelloWorld
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //for filter
        //these items are "Dir b"
        List<Dir> sides = new List<Dir>{ Dir.forward, Dir.back, Dir.left, Dir.right };

        //assume that the previous node is at the front of this node, and the next is at the back
        //These two are "Dir c"
        var incoming = Dir.forward;
        var outgoing = Dir.back;

        //filter them out from the list, so that only the 'unused sides' are left
        sides.Remove(incoming);  //in real scenario, it must be decorated with: if(incoming != null)
        sides.Remove(outgoing);  //the same as above

        //testing if the filter really worked
        foreach (var side in sides)
            Console.Write(side);
    }
}
```

**Why do I think that the code shouldn't work?**

Though I am getting the same public member from the struct, it is "struct", which means that I am getting the copied version of that object, but not getting a reference.

For easier distinction, let's just call the original static members of Dir as "Dir a" and copied versions are "Dir b" and "Dir c". I will leave these names in the comment as well in the code.

In identity perspective, "Dir b" is not "Dir a", and of course, is not "Dir c", too, since they all are different instances.

In that case, isn't it that the `List.Remove(T)` is supposed to think the "Dir c" is not "Dir b"?

Or, are basic behaviour of C#'s equality operator based on the object's values, instead of their identities?

Comment: For value types, the default implementation of `Equals` compares all fields, see [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetype.equals)

Comment: Side note: please re-read the [mre] guidance on posting the code - there is far too much code to demonstrate behavior for a value type: `int` should be perfectly fine for that and would need much shorter code. Also indeed it would be good idea to include links to documentation you've read (presumably you've seen one linked by @KlausGütter but maybe misunderstood something).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Or, are basic behaviour of C#'s equality operator based on the object's values ... ?

The equality operator  (`==`) is not defined for `Dir`.

But `List<T>` uses the `Equals()` method for Remove(), and that does indeed perform a member-wise comparison.
This comparison uses reflection so it's not very performant.

You could consider [implementing Equality yourself](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/how-to-define-value-equality-for-a-type#struct-example) or to use [`record struct` or `record`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/record) instead of struct.

Answer (score 0):

Let's follow the documentation, starting with [`List.Remove()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.remove?view=net-7.0). There we have this excerpt in the Remarks section:

> If type `T` implements the IEquatable generic interface, the equality comparer is the Equals method of that interface; otherwise, the default equality comparer is Object.Equals.

I don't see any `IEquatable<T>` on the `Dir` struct, so let's look at [the `Object.Equals` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.equals?view=net-7.0). The Remarks section of the documentation now gives us this information:

> The type of comparison between the current instance and the obj parameter depends on whether the current instance is a reference type or a value type.

> If the current instance is a value type, the Equals(Object) method tests for value equality. Value equality means the following:
>
> - The two objects are of the same type ...
> - The values of the public and private fields of the two objects are equal.

As `struct` indicates value type, we can see the documentation definitively shows `List.Remove()` will compare the fields.

---

*But what if `Dir` was a reference type (class)?*

In that case, the objects would **still be equal**. In fact, since both the list and the `incoming`/`outgoing` variables are assigned from static members in `Dir`, they'll be assigned as *references to the same objects.* So now it won't matter whether you use reference or value equality... the comparer is going to match either way.